# Как переименовать файл по шаблону?

Tags: ant

Использую [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) для сборки проекта. Требуется переименовать один файл, но заранее неизвестно его имя, известен только шаблон. Как переименовать файл с помощью ant, если команда Rename не поддерживает регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать через move, где dir и todir имеют одинаковое значение, и передать туда [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html).

```
  <move todir="${dir}">
    <fileset dir="${dir}" />
    <mapper>
    <mapper type="regexp"
            from="test(.*).txt"
            to="renamed.txt"/>
    </mapper>
  </move>
```